# Node.js How to parse / excute javascript receive from node server?

Tags: jquery, node.js, http

I'm new on Node, I have the following problem, I have a http://mydomain.com/mypage.php that do some stuff, and I want to call http://mydomain.com:8080 (where is located the node server).

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
                  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
                  res.end('$("#messages").append("<br> test123");');

                });
server.listen(8080);
```

Seems to work, because I receive in my client :

```
$("#messages").append("<br> test123");
```

but the code receive, is not execute!

any idea ?

thanks in advance
Dany

php Code simplified (mypage.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>demo game </title>


<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="messages"></div>
<input type="text" id="text-input">
<input type="button" value="Send" id="send-button">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, show us html code that includes http://mydomain.com:8080

Comment: How do you call `...:8080` from PHP?

Comment: Either place `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080"></script>` right before `</body>`, or wrap the response in `$(function(){ ... });` (domready).

Comment: Have you tried `application/javascript` instead of `text/javascript`?

Answer (score 2):

try returning this

```
$(function(){
  $("#messages").append("<br> test123"); 
})
```

this might be happening because script is being executed before  `div#messages` is loaded and hence there is no reference to `div#messages`

Comment: but the problem, is that is the content (url / fs) change I see on the server when i console.log it, but from the client side, it stay with the original version , do you have an idea ? BTW thanks to all of you Rob,juan,karacas

Comment: yeah.. the content you are sending from the server side isn't the problem. The time when the code is being executed in the client is.

Comment: I'm lost, I working on the same machine, should I use socket.io , what should I do ? My problem is the following : I have some cron/script that generate a specific file(javascript) per user connected, and I want want to send to the specific client(user) is own code, there is a way to do that ?

Comment: what im saying is that according to the problem that is given by you here the problem is only client side and you should return the script as specified by my ans. what you have asked in the previous comment requires an entirely new question